# Origin of the Ashkenazi Pronunciation?

Tags: hebrew, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

What is the actual story behind the Ashkenazi way of pronunciation? I am uncertain as to whether Ashkenazim consider their form of pronunciation older than Sephardi, just an alternative, or... Any help greatly appreciated!

The question, in summary: is there historical evidence to support that either Ashkenazi or Sephardi pronunciation is more related to the form of Hebrew Moshe used?

Comment: I think you'll find that, just like all schemes of pronunciation, the two traditions have a common ancestor and the same amount of time evolving.  Is this question about the "actual story" or how Ashkenazim consider it?  It seems to be two different questions.

Comment: Someone who thought there weren't enough S sounds already decided to make the taf also be one.. I don't know.

Comment: [This article, "The Phonology of Ashkenazic" is excerpted from the book *Hebrew in Ashkenaz: A Language in Exile*](http://dovidkatz.net/dovid/PDFLinguistics/1993b.pdf). The book has several relevant articles by various authors, but this particular chapter by Dovid Katz is specifically about the sound of the language and what phonological shifts happened over time. He is a respected scholar of the history of both Yiddish and Ashkenazic Hebrew. Regarding what Moses spoke, no one today speaks it, although Yemeni or Iraqi Hebrew may be close since they use certain consonants that Europeans do not.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that in Old German, "th" is pronounced "s."